# LiftMaster 1280R door won't close

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a somewhat ancient LiftMaster 1280R and the door does not close. The light blinks as if it were a safety sensor issue, but the lights on both sensors are solid. I've tried replacing the safety sensors, and the new sensors also light up solid, but the door still won't close.

I've confirmed it's not a wiring issue by wiring the sensors with short leads directly to the garage door opener and taped them so they were facing each other.

I can manually close the door without issue. If I hold my wall button down, the door will close (I believe this bypasses the safety sensor somehow). The above behavior resurfaces once I let go of the button regardless of the position of the door at the time. My other door opens and closes with a single press of the wall button.

Is there anything else I can try before replacing the whole garage door opener?

Comment: did you change the battery on remote and pair it again, by putting the garage door opener in pairing mode (blinking light)

Comment: Make darn sure the two "eyes" on each side are aligned correctly.  I have a door that sometimes does the same.  The lights on the eyes are good, but the door won't close unless I hold the button down.  Adjusting the eyes again makes it work properly.

Comment: @Huesmann The sensors are currently taped to each other so the sender and receiver are touching. No room for error there.

Comment: @Ruskes The behavior is the same with the wall button and remote, so it's not a remote issue. The remote is newly purchased and paired however (same day as the replacement eyes). I have two remotes in addition to the wall button and both removes are able to operate the other door perfectly. They can both open, but not close, the door in question.

Comment: Thank you for additional info, it is hard to diagnose from where I am. Typically if one of the sensor is blocked the garage opener light should flash. You can try disconnecting the light sensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I wasn't able to determine the problem. I replaced the entire garage door opener unit but used the existing safety sensors, and they function as expected. I assume that the problem was with a component on the main board of garage door opener.

The new opener is working perfectly.